# Cancel closing modal from result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can I write some function to cancel closing from result?
Bad idea save model in ModalInstanceCtrl.

```
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
        $scope.edit =function (id) {
            var modal = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
            });

            modal.result.then(function(model) {
                if (somethink_wrong) {
                    ***CANCEL CLOSING***
                }
            });
        };
    }]);

    app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {    
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.model);
        };    
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call a service in your ModalInstanceCtrl to check if "something is wrong", before actually closing it ?
Thus, you could make that when you actually close it, the modal passed to the anonymous function in the "then" would be valid data, and you're sure nothing is wrong.

```
  app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {
        $scope.edit =function (id) {
            var modal = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
            });

            modal.result.then(function(model) {
                *There is nothing wrong because we already checked :)*
            });
        };
    }]);

    app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', yourService function ($scope, $modalInstance, yourService) {    
        $scope.ok = function () {
            if (yourService.checkNothingWrong()) {
                 $modalInstance.close($scope.model);
            }
            else {
                 *inform user something is wrong*
            }
        };    
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }]);
```

And injecting a service is maybe not even necessary. Why don't you simply make your validation in the modal controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you basically can't easily. close and dismiss are kinda terminal. You are too late in the modal cycle.

The "will i close or not" logic correct place in inside your Modal controller, in the "ok" and "cancel" methods. The real question would be : why can't you do your validation here ?